# finger protocol ignores .plan and .project files of other users unless running with sudo

Tags: server, permissions

I'm running a small server Ubuntu 23.04 and have sudo privileges. I have a few other folks on the server and we are trying out finger. We've made .plan and .project files. However, when we `finger username` with our own username, we can see the full project and plan info listed. But if anyone finger's someone else's username, it returns  there login name and directory but not .plan or .project. Instead, that section says "No plan." for example even though it exists in their home directory. HOWEVER, if i run `sudo finger username` then it works.

So this seems like a permissions issue, but I'm not sure how to fix since the other users can't run sudo. How can I fix this as an admin to allow other users to run finger correctly without sudo?

Same issue when testing with `pinky username -l` as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a permissions/access problem. That's why it works for `root`.

Read `man finger`, it mentions HOME directory needing `o+x` (searchability) to make `~/.nofinger` work.

Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Consider:

```
#!/bin/bash
# create a new group "fingers"
sudo addgroup fingers 
for u in "you and a few other folks" ; do
    # add user to "fingers" group
    sudo adduser "$u" fingers
    uhome="$(getent passwd "$u" | cut -d: -f6)"
    # allow group read and search for user's $HOME directory 
    sudo chmod g+rx "$uhome"
    # allow group read of .plan, .project
    sudo chmod g+r "$uhome"/{.plan,.project}
done
```

Then, when each of the users logsout and login (groups are set up by `login`), `finger` should work.

Comment: i wasn't able to get your script to work even after logging out and back in for each user (i tested with test users). i still get the same outcome, but when i chmod o+x a user's home directory then finger works so thanks for the hint

Comment: "Couldn't get your script to work"? Details, please.

Comment: in other words, the script ran ok. then i logged out the users and logged back in as a test user. when i run finger test-user i still get the same issue that test-user's plan and project don't exist. however, if i irun chmod o+x ~username then after that finger will work on that user.